# Using unsigned char array to store memory efficiently

Tags: c++, byte

I was looking for an efficient way to store memory, so I realized that an unsigned char uses only one byte of memory. Thinking about it I made a small program that obtains the size of bytes of each variable.

```
int main() {

    int myInt = 10;
    long long myLongLong = 10;
    unsigned char charArray1[] = { 10, 10, 10, 10 };
    unsigned char charArray2[] = { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 };

    std::cout << "Using sizeof () we get:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "myInt -> " << sizeof(myInt) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "myLongLong -> " << sizeof(myLongLong) << std::endl;

    std::cout << "charArray1 -> " << sizeof(charArray1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "charArray2 -> " << sizeof(charArray2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Using sizeof () we get:
myInt -> 4
myLongLong -> 8
charArray1 -> 4
charArray2 -> 8
```

Is it correct to say that I can store bytes in an unsigned char array? If correct, how can I get some matrix elements from unsigned char and assign them to a variable?

Example: If an integer occupies 4 bytes in memory, I can get 4 elements from the unsigned char array and assign it to an integer.

Comment: To store an `int` that is 4 bytes large, you will need 4 `unsigned char` that are each 1 byte large. There is no way to get a reduction in memory doing this.

Comment: "Can I store bytes in an unsigned char array?" Yes. "How can I get some matrix elements from unsigned char and assign them to a variable?" That depends on how you stored them in the `char` array in the first place. "Should you do this?" No. It requires casting (cheap) but that breaks type safety. It will lead to bugs and make your program harder to maintain. There's an argument for compressing data if you're transmitting it, since the milliseconds saved by sending fewer bytes more than make up for the extra microseconds it takes to decompress the received data.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That way it doesn't save space, my goal is to manipulate bytes manually.

Comment: @Davindodeumlugar Please clarify what exactly you want to do in the question. You can already (to some degree) manipulate bytes that make up an object directly by casting a pointer to the object to `unsigned char*`/`std::byte*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it correct to say that I can store bytes in an unsigned char array?

Yes.

> If an integer occupies 4 bytes in memory, I can get 4 elements from the unsigned char array and assign it to an integer.

If and only if the array contains the bytes of the integer in the exact same format as the system uses natively, then you can do this:

```
static_assert(sizeof myInt == sizeof charArray1);
std::memcpy(&myInt, charArray1, sizeof myInt);
```

If the format isn't the same, then it is still possible to calculate the value as long as you know what the bytes represent.

Comment: I'd recommend putting `<=` in that assert instead or `==`, or I feel it risks confusing some new developers.